# CodeIgniter: Page not found when passing parameters to a controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to pass parameters to a control in codeigniter, but I'm getting 404 page not found error, I don't get it, I did what the guide says: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#passing-uri-segments-to-your-methods

When I remove the params in the index function and just access the controller everything works fine, but I can't pass a value to it...

Here is the code the way I'm trying to send a param: `http://mysite/123`

```
<?php
class Main extends Controller {

    function index($username) {

        echo $username;

    }

}
?>
```

How can I get more info regarding this error from codeigniter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL needs to be `http://mysite/Main/index/123`.

CodeIgniter URLs are `http://<url>/<Controller>/<Method>/<params>`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the /application/config/routes.php file and set the default controller to main like this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'main';
```

Answer (score 0):

**//For CI 2.0.2
//main.php**

```
<?php
class Main extends CI_Controller {

    function index($username) {

        echo $username;

    }

}
?>
```

**// application/config/routes.php**
$route['default_controller'] = 'main';

And then try this in URL::
http://mysite/index.php/main/index/123

hope this works for you

Comment: i want to display profile detail of users of user name 123... and my url must look like http://mysite/123 in codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the data is passed only when there are more than two uri segments.

Try this,

```
<?php
class Main extends Controller {

    function index() {
        $username = $this->uri->segment(3);
        echo $username;
    }
}
?>
```

And then go to http://mysite/index.php/main/index/123

Comment: i want to display profile detail of users of user name 123... and my url must look like mysite/123 in codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

Add this function into your control.  This will help out get passing arg into index function if method doesn't.

```php
    function _remap($method)
    {
      $param_offset = 2;

      // Default to index
      if ( ! method_exists($this, $method))
      {
        // We need one more param
        $param_offset = 1;
        $method = 'index';
      }

      // Since all we get is $method, load up everything else in the URI
      $params = array_slice($this->uri->rsegment_array(), $param_offset);

      // Call the determined method with all params
      call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

route file in add this code and any parameters accepted for your home page

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'main'; 
$route['(:any)'] = "main/$1";
```