# Passing parameter to controller always get "Page Not Found" - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to pass a parameter to my controller functions from my views but I always get "Page Not Found".
I've been looking for any solutions possible for my problem from [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998771/codeigniter-page-not-found-when-passing-parameters-to-a-controller), [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074993/codeigniter-passing-parameter-to-controller-index) but I still couldn't find working solutions and I still don't know what could be the problem. I think I've set everything right, but it's not working. Please tell me if there's something I'm doing wrong.

Here is my controller: Controll.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Controll extends CI_Controller{

public function about($thing){
    $case = "About Us";
    $data['page'] = $case;
    $data['p'] = $thing;
    print($thing);
    //$this->load->view('/header/header',$data);
    $this->load->view('about_us',$data);
    $this->load->view('/footer/footer');
}
public function mountain_destination($thing){
    $data['page'] = "Mountain Destination";
    $data['p'] = $thing;
    //$this->load->view('/header/header',$data);
    $this->load->view('mountain_destination',$data);
    $this->load->view('/footer/footer');
}
}

?>
```

Here's my routes setting:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "controll/$1";
$route['default_controller'] = "controll";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

And here's one of my script called by onClick that tries to call that controller function:

```
function goTab(thing,tab){
    switch(thing){
        case "about":
            $body.load("<?php echo site_url('about'); ?>/"+$(tab).text().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,''));
        break;
        case "mountain":
            $body.load("<?php echo site_url('mountain_destination'); ?>/"+$(tab).text().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,''));
        break;
    }
```

My script runs well and it produces right url. For example, I put parameter "myteam" into "goTab" function, it produces link like this:
"http://127.0.0.1/about/myteam". This link's supposed to call "about" function inside my controller and pass "myteam" as parameter. But instead it returns "Page Not Found". And when I try to call "about" function without any parameters like this: "http://127.0.0.1/about", I get missing argument error like this:

```
Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for Controll::about()

Filename: controllers/Controll.php

Line Number: 22
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove this and see `$route['(:any)'] = "controll/$1";`

Comment: @Abdulla It makes my whole functions to not working (produces "Page Not Found" with or without paramter).

Comment: Remove closing PHP tag in controller. Never use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing it to your `about` method. You're looking for a method called `myteam` within your `Controll` controller.

Amend your Routes to this;

```
$route['about/(:any)'] = 'controll/about/$1';
$route['mountain_destination/(:any)'] = 'controll/mountain_destination/$1';
```

Hope this helps.

This answer of mine might also help you;

[Codeigniter Menu from Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140159/codeigniter-menu-from-database/31140658#31140658)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable and pass it within `constructor` and simply use that whenever you need as

```
class Controll extends CI_Controller {

    private $thing;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->thing = $this->uri->segment(3);
    }

    public function about() {
        $data['p'] = $this->thing;
        echo $this->thing;
    }

    public function mountain_destination($thing) {
        $data['p'] = $this->thing;
        echo $this->thing;
    }

}
```